# Otto events handling order

Tags: android, otto

Please help me to figure out if the following scenarios are valid if I'm going to use Otto Bus lib.

1. If I need to ensure the order of subscriber execution. I have two component that are listening for the same event type,is there the Otto Bus
   capability which can guarantee that constantly component1 handles an event
   before component2. Could the order I register them provide me
   that?
2. According to the Otto documentation

   > Posting to the bus is a synchronous action so when program execution
   >   continues it is guaranteed that all subscribers have been called.

   Does it mean that any of event subscribers are not executed in
   parallel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting an event, Otto iterates through a `Set` of handlers to dispatch the event to them.

Since `Set` is an unordered collection, it is not guaranteed that this will happen in the order you've registered them (or any particular order).

The relevant part from the source code:

```
Set<Class<?>> dispatchTypes = flattenHierarchy(event.getClass());

boolean dispatched = false;
for (Class<?> eventType : dispatchTypes) {
  Set<EventHandler> wrappers = getHandlersForEventType(eventType);

  if (wrappers != null && !wrappers.isEmpty()) {
    dispatched = true;
    for (EventHandler wrapper : wrappers) {
      enqueueEvent(event, wrapper);
    }
  }
}
```